# MinGW gcc can’t resolve system header files

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw

I’m trying to compile My C apps for windows 64bit with MinGW64+msys.

After installing them I  started `gcc` for sample program and got following error.

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcc a.c

a.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

C:\MinGW\bin>
```

But `stdio.h` file is in `C:\MinGW\include`.

What should I do for resolving stdio.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try: `gcc a.c -IC:\MinGW\include` and see if it compiles.

Comment: I did but situation haven’t changed.

Comment: You can try this page - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO. In particular, what does `gcc -v -c a.c` output?

Comment: I found problem from this output message. GCC searches header files for directory I never care. I've removed header files from there .