# Unable to compile program with <ncurses.h> header using MinGW

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, ncurses, pdcurses

I am using this program https://github.com/aviikc/CIS2500_fileeditor. There exists a `ncurses` and `ncursesw` folder in  `c:MinGW/include` .
but running

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 ./src/fileeditor.c -Iinclude -lncurses -o ./bin/output
```

its throws an error:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 ./src/fileeditor.c -Iinclude -lncurses -o ./bin/output
In file included from ./src/fileeditor.c:1:
include/fileeditor.h:1:10: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ncurses.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

I understand its not being able to find the library.
I had used `mingw-get` install `ncurses` and `mingw-get` install pdcurses to install. Can someone please guide. Its a possibility I've messed up the whole program. I'm new to c and c++. My intention was to create a hangman like game with a text user interface.

Comment: *"I understand its not being able to find the library."* - the compiler cannot find the header (not the library). It looks like you need to add `-I c:/MinGW/include` to your compile command line (or however you specify a path on MinGW). Also see [MinGW gcc can’t resolve system header files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21129367/608639), [Cannot include a header in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27632846/608639) and friends.

Comment: -Ic:/MinGW/include/ncurses (assuming ncurses.h is in that directory)